# Laravel 5 update without id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem in Laravel 5. When I update a record in database, I get error `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`. In the controller, I use WHERE clause to get the record I want to update. My primary key is not id and the type is bigInteger. I've tried adding `protected $primaryKey` in the model but it doesn't work for bigInteger. Is there any way to use my own primary key instead of using id?

Controller

```
$item = Item::where('item_id','=',$item_id)->first();
$item.name = $name;
$item.type = $type;
$item.save();
```

Comment: Show the controller.

Comment: I've added the controller

Comment: Try `Item::find($item_id)`. Also, you are using ruby syntax in php, it should be `$item->` instead of `$item.` in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

pls add this line to your Item.php model

`class Item extends Model {`

// add this line only 
`protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';`

`//..... the rest of your model`

since your using custom id name, laravel will not know what is your primary key without you specify it

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's orm `$primaryKey` default is `'id'`.

When orm update, it use the sql like:

```
... where {$this->primaryKey} = {$this->{$this->primaryKey}}
```

So when you class extends orm.

You should redefine `protected $primaryKey = '<your_table_primary_key>';`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$item = Item::where('item_id', $item_id)->first();`  If still don't working add also `protected $primaryKey = "item_id";`  to your model